# GraphCDN: This endpoint requires you to be authenticated

Tags: caching, graphql

I'm just starting to use GraphCDN with GraphQL and there's something that I don't understand. I set up my service as detailed in the documentation and now I have `**.graphcdn.app/` caching my original `https://***.com/graphql`

Now to test I'm trying the new endpoint. But while some endpoints are open and need no authentication on my graphql api, the same endpoint would give the error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "This endpoint requires you to be authenticated.",
    "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql#authenticating-with-graphql"
  }
}
```

in GraphCDN. Any ideas on how I can get around this, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you created a service that proxies through to the GitHub GraphQL API, hence why the API responds with a "This endpoint requires you to be authenticated" error that has a docs.github.com link in it.

In order to point it at your own GraphQL API (which doesn't require authentication), change the "Origin URL" in your service's settings to the URL of your GraphQL API:

[image: Screenshot of the GraphCDN dashboard showing the "Your GraphQL API URL" setting]

We're happy to help further with that, feel free to reach out to our excellent customer success team via the chat bubble on the dashboard anytime!

*Source: I'm one of the cofounders of GraphCDN.*

Comment: The problem has been fixed but I had not updated my question
However, thank you very much sir for the very very clear answer

Comment: And btw, your service is amazing. Hats off

Comment: Thanks for the nice words, glad to hear you like it!